# Node Js looping at specific times

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cron

Okay, so I have a node.js rest API and I am using a mysql database with it.

The data in mysql data base is fetched from say, axyz.com/api?token

Now I want to call this api and update my data, every five minutes, from Monday to Friday,
Between 12pm and 4pm.

How can I do this in node.js ? It should be called every 5 minutes automatically.

Comment: `setInterval()` is what you are looking for.  This question is asked pretty regularly so there are probably many dups

Comment: No but it is also an API, so should I create a new thread for it ? Should I use a new terminal to run this script ? I am new to Node.JS so I have no clue how can you do it